# How long can I keep the Str bonus from "Strength of my Enemy"?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, psionics

The Psychic Power 'Strength of my Enemy' allows you to enhance any (natural) weapon you have to deal one point of strength damage with each succesful hit. This drained strength is then added to your own as an enhancement bonus.

The power itself clearly states that it lasts for 1 round per lvl. However, the effect of this power is NOT "you get a strength bonus". The effect of this power is "As long as the effect last, you can drain strength from your enemies."
So how long does the strength bonus last? Indefinitely? Until the effect ends? Or "1 round/lvl from the moment you drained this specific strength point?"
Or, to keep bookkeeping easy: "1 round/level from the moment you drained the last point from a specific creature", since each creature's drained strength is counted as a seperate bonus.

Answer (score 1):

The power does lack an official statement for the bonus’s duration and it should have one, but I have always seen it ruled that the bonus ends when the power does.

Answer (score 1):

[*Strength of my Enemy*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/strengthofMyEnemy.htm) clearly indicates the duration of the effect that it grants:

> **Duration**: 1 round/level (D)
>   You gain the ability to siphon away your enemy’s strength for your own use. One of your natural or manufactured weapons becomes the instrument of your desire, and deals 1 point of Strength damage on each successful hit. *You gain that point of Strength as an enhancement bonus to your Strength score.* Strength you siphon from different foes is tracked separately—the total siphoned from each individual foe is considered a separate enhancement bonus to your Strength (maximum +8), and you gain only the highest total. (*emphasis mine*)

There is no indication in the text of the power that the duration of the enhancement bonus you siphon is in any way different to the power.